# Plotting the Arrhenius curve without the rate constant

Tags: kinetics

I was carrying out an experiment about finding the activation energy of the Maillard reaction using the Arrhenius equation. Since I didn't know the rate constant for the reaction due to the complex reaction mechanism of the Maillard Reaction, I tweaked the rate reaction to fit into the Arrhenius reaction.
$$\text{Rate}=k[\text{glucose}]^m[\text{asparagine}]^n \\\implies k=\frac{\text{Rate}}{[\text{glucose}]^m[\text{asparagine}]^n } \\\implies k=([\text{glucose}]^m[\text{asparagine}]^n)\,\frac{\mathrm d[\text{product}]}{\mathrm dt} \\\implies k=\frac{c}{t}$$ where $c=([\text{glucose}]^m[\text{asparagine}]^n)\,\mathrm d[\text{product}]$. By ln both sides, I got $\ln k=\ln c-\ln t$ which I then subbed into the Arrhenius equation to get $$\ln c-\ln t=-\frac{E_\mathrm a}{R}\times\frac{1}{T}+\ln A$$ By manipulating, I got $$\ln t=\frac{E_\mathrm a}{R}\times\frac{1}{T}-\ln A+\ln c$$ Which then produce the below graph based on the experimental data[image]
However, the gradient is positive which technically should be negative according to other Arrhenius plots I have seen. Does anyone know if this is correct or is there something I missed out?

Comment: Ignoring whether the manipulation you give is correct, *experimentally* it is possible to have a positive slope if the reaction is complex. For example if the rate expression has the form $k_{overall} \sim k_1/k_2$ where both rate constants have an Arrhenious form, the result is proportional to $e^{-(E_1-E_2)/RT}$ so the effective activation energy $E_1-E_2$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: I implicitly assume the reaction is stopped at time t at the same concentration of the product, so c is constant. otherwise the slope Ea/R is affected by additional slope d(ln c)/d(1/T)

Comment: But as X axis variable is 1/T,  the ln t as Y should raise with raising X. as rates increase with temperature. Is possible you have seen charts ln rate versus ln T ?

Comment: So this graph is actually possible? The other graphs showed lnk

Comment: Please remember that descriptive terms or names of quantities (such as $\text{Rate}$) shall not be arranged in the form of an equation and shall not be used in the place of proper quantity symbols.

Comment: Could Rate be the change in product over time? Since the change in product is always constant since I was measuring the time taken for completion, then Rate=Total product/Time where time is the variable?

Comment: @Matthew Tan Yes, the rate is the 1st derivative of the product concentration over the time, what is the same as the product change over time, if it is constant over time. But why do you ask, when you have already correctly stated it in the question ? You can easily replace ln t by ln rate as Y variable.